# How do I undo Flash Player Update

Tags: flash

Flash player updated and now nothing works how do i return it to the way it was yesterday without using a computer restore point that is set to 6 months ago?

Comment: This is a good question... for [su]

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall your Flash Player first using their uninstaller and then installing the version you want from here [Archived Flash Player page](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html)